# "how much longer do you plan on [X]ing..."

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is the above structure grammatically correct, or just sort of common, or not correct but common enough to use?

Comment: What possible problem do you see?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that there are eternal rules of English grammar. When an expression becomes 'common enough to use', even if the grammar involved is irregular, it becomes acceptable in some if not all registers. 'How much longer do you plan on staying' is fine conversationally. I guessed it was quite acceptable in more formal registers also, and AHDEL agrees. General reference.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "on" does there. I see what it does in "don't plan on [X]ing for long...", as in 'expecting', but... I'm throwing doubts around, seeing if anything sticks. Days before sending a translation for editing...

Comment: Yeah, joeav, as Mr. Ashworth mentioned - the question sounds fine, you could also say, "How much longer do you plan to continue Xing?"

Comment: @Little Eva The default addressee is the originator of the question or answer.

Comment: The 'plan + ing-form' expression involves, I'd guess, prepositional (in this case particle) deletion from the 'plan on + ing-form' expression. If true, the question should be "Why do some people drop the 'on'?" Prepositions are often dropped from temporal expressions (See you [on] Tuesday) and certain verb + preposition constructions (fought [against] the Nazis; brushed [against] his leg; appealed [against] the decision; gained [in] confidence; booed [at] the villain ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OED's entry for the specific phrasal verb is definition **1e** under **plan**...

> verb, intr. colloq. **to plan on**
>    *to intend to carry out (some action); to anticipate or be prepared for.*

...for which their first citation is...

> **1914** E. R. Burroughs *Tarzan of Apes* xxvii. 370
>    [She is **planning on** our going up there the first of the week.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20planning%20on%20our%20going%20up%20there%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

It's a perfectly common usage today, and the fact that a well-known and competent writer used it over a century ago suggests to me it's pointless debating whether the usage is "grammatical" or not.

Comment: Yes; _plan on_ in '_plan on_ going' is certainly more cohesive than _boo at_ in '_boo at_ the villain'. I'm guessing that some MWVs can drop the particles, as some verb + PPs can drop the preposition.